# How to use html added script in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have one html file and js file that i need to use in my lwc components How do i use this ?

Html file

```
 <head>
    <body onload=loadConfig()>  
     
     </body>
    </head>
```

and my js file

```
loadConfig(){
const newNode = document.createElement("config-node");
document.body.append(newNode);

newNode.addEventListener("configSaved", function(event) {
       
    });
```

These thing i need to use in my LWC how do i do this . Appreciate your help on this . Thanks in advance,

```
<template>
    <div class="container" lwc:dom="manual">
    </div>
</template>
```

in js file

```
import Config from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Config';

renderedCallback() {
        if (this.framewokrInitialized ) {
            return;
        }
        this.framewokrInitialized = true;
    
        Promise.all([
       loadScript(this, Config + '/Config.js'),
       loadScript(this, Config + '/Zone.js'), ]).then(() => { 
            this.loadCallable();
           }).catch(e => {
            console.log('err'+e);
        });;
    LoadCallable()
    {
    const newMode= document.createElement("config-mode");
    ****document.body.append(newMode )**; --> Error here document.body.append Is not a function**
    newNode.addEventListener("configSaved", function(event) {

    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I will suggest to use two things

> 1. loadScript
> 2. lwc:dom= manual

create a div tag in HTML with lwc:dom=manual, and now

Instead of using a different HTML file, you can write that login inside the JS file only so load it using loadScript and append your code to that div tag where we added  lwc:dom= manual

Edit:

```
   const divelement = document.createElement("div");
   this.template.querySelector("div.container").appendChild(divelement);
```

Let me know if you need more suggestions in this way.

Comment: I have stuck at this point.
const newNode = document.createElement("config-node");
document.body.append(newNode);
**document.body.append is not a function**

Comment: You mean this line is written inside the js file? or it's in LWC js file?

Comment: I have updated my Code. Please help me . Stuck at past 6 hrs. Written in LWC Js file

Comment: Goto Setup → Session Settings → Uncheck 'Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning Web Components and Aura Components'

and try then

Comment: @Gopal.Its already uncheked only .How to add body in LWC target Elements.

Comment: I added a code line in my answer try that way

Comment: directly you can not access the document.body

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147621/discussion-between-starboy-the-and-gopal).